# Can Transients be used to store sensitive data?

Tags: transient

Can I use WordPress Transients to store 'sensitive' data? For example login tokens or Captcha answers?

As far as I know all themes and plugins have access to transients. What would be another good way to store this kind of details?

Edit:
The reason I ask this question is that I am creating a 2 Factor Authentication plugin that generates a login token. This token is sent via SMS or e-mail to the user. What would be a safe way to store this token.

Comment: "safe" from what whom and when? there is not really anything which is "just safe". Once you give any user some access he might be able to use some security issue to get the secret, the trick is to balance between functionality and security and not to worry about the NSA trying to break into a server, but about a more realistic threats.

Comment: You're right. I have decided to use `User Meta` within WordPress to store those keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, transients is on your server, not accessible by front end client.
You can use also update_option()
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_option

Comment: Okay, so it is considered 'safe' if I would store a 2 Factor Auth *sms* code as a transient. I am not sure If would need to use my own database table or not. 

On the other hand. Any plugin or theme could expose the 2FA sms code via the transients API.

Answer (score 1):

No. Nothing in wordpress environment is isolated enough to be used as a safe place for keeping secrets. Any other code can use you code to get the data (therefor encrypting things will not help).

If it is a true secret, then store it as a cookie/local storage on the user's PC if you are trying to save the effort required from the user typing his password/token/whatever.

Comment: The idea is that the token is being send via SMS. It wouldn't be any secure if the user could read the token :')

Comment: Oh you are talking about doing DRM? it can never be done if a user can manipulate your code

Comment: I have edited my question about why I was asking this.

Comment: cookie/local storage? Really? It's the first advice on how to NOT store sensitive information.

Comment: @OksanaRomaniv why? what is more secure than not storing the info on the server at all?

Comment: @MarkKaplun, storing info on the server is much more secure than storing info in the user browser, because if you store it in the browser, you expose it to other scripts that can run in the browser (for example, user extensions or other scripts on the page). If you store information on the server, only you have access to that information and potentially people who can huck it. If you store it in browser (e.g. localStorage), the pool of people that could get access to it is much larger.

Comment: @OksanaRomaniv In the real live, in order to get access to browser data you need to get access to the device by an untrusted person which unless you are being a specific target for an sophisticated attack is unlikely to happen. A site being accessable to attacker all the time is a much easier attack surface, and then we have all the bad code wordpress sites usually have. The best thing is not to have secrets stored anywhere in a permanent way, but if even google thinks that it is secure enough to store passwords in the browser, it seems like a worthy alternative.